# Can't restart Apache on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, restart

I tried to add new domain but after I tried to restart apache I get this:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-08-17 07:58:06 UTC; 15s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2026 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/sentora/panel/] does not exist
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/sentora/hostdata/trgovac/public_html/trgovac_rs] does not exist
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/sentora/logs/domains/banko-sistemi/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/svi.conf:687
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 17 07:58:06 server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 17 07:58:06 server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 17 07:58:06 server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 17 07:58:06 server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anybody have an idea why is this happening? How can I restart apache?

Comment: try sudo service --status-all : to check all the services and verify if there is + or - sign on left side of apache .

Comment: People not reading their error messages make me sad :(

Comment: Chombe, have a read through those error messages. It looks like you have configured a directory that doesn't exist. Maybe you deleted the directory?

Answer (score 1):

There are some permission problems in your installation. You can find that from the last 2 lines of the following logs:

```
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/sentora/panel/] does not exist
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/sentora/hostdata/trgovac/public_html/trgovac_rs] does not exist
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/sentora/logs/domains/banko-sistemi/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/svi.conf:687
Aug 17 07:58:06 server apache2[2026]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
```

There are 2 warnings (These are only warnings and won't let Apache fail to start but they are worth noting). You have configured somewhere in your virtual hosts' configurations 2 document roots that do not exist. One in `/etc/sentora/panel/` and another in `/var/sentora/hostdata/trgovac/public_html/trgovac_rs`.

However, the error that is causing Apache to fail to start, is the fact that it is trying to create/modify a log that Apache doesn't have access to in `/var/sentora/logs/domains/banko-sistemi/`.

To fix that, make sure the directory exists, if it doesn't create it and give access to Apache to modify it:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/sentora/logs/domains/banko-sistemi
sudo chown -u www-data /var/sentora/logs/domains/banko-sistemi
```

In case you have changed the default Apache user, change `www-data` to whatever user you chose for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this.
I create the directory "banko-sistemi" on this location /var/sentora/logs/domains/banko-sistemi/.

After that I restart apache without any problem.